# How to deploy a maven project as jar file

Tags: java, maven

I have read a lot into 'building' the pom.xml file which I have done multiple times after cleaning the project.

I have put package and compile when setting goals and tried installing. It creates a 'SNAPSHOT' jar file but when I try to execute it nothing happens.

I tried to execute it on the command line (CMD) to see errors and I receive this:

> no main manifest attribute, in smart.mirror-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You need the `maven-jar-plugin` and must specify the main class: `tld.domain.ClassName`.

Comment: Is this a plain command line app or a Spring Boot app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need to use the maven jar plugin and define the main class.

```
 <plugin> 
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
     <configuration>
          <archive>
              <manifest>
                  <mainClass>
                     com.yourpackage.YourMainClass
                  </mainClass>
              </manifest>
          </archive>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Usually, you do have dependencies, which you can package into your own jar by using the Shade Plugin if necessary.

Comment: Where do I need to add this? Then do I just do Run As -> Build or Run As -> Install?

Comment: `C:\Users\user\Desktop\smart.mirror\target>java -jar smart.mirror-V1.0.B.1.0.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mashape/unirest/
ttp/exceptions/UnirestException at iezon.smart.mirror.App.main(App.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mashape.unirest.http.exception
.UnirestException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)`

Comment: I now get this error, looks like it isn't compiling the dependencies

Comment: Unirest is the first dependency the project uses on the execution stack, it looks to me like the build did not include any of the dependencies in the pom.xml, any ideas how to include the dependencies into the build? [Heres an image of the pom file.](https://ibb.co/eh1QBp)

Comment: Actually you are right, I get this `Error: Could not find or load main class iezon.smart.mirror.App` when I try to Run as Java Application, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to add the dependency to your pom and than rebuild it. Please add this dependency to your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>
    <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.9</version>
</dependency>
```

After this, right click the project and select maven and clean it. After cleaning, follow same steps and select build. It will build the executable jar.

You must use Maven Assembly Plugin instead of Jar to deploy the dependencies with executable Jar. It's missing in your pom. It should be similar to below mentioned plugins configuration:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
    <descriptorRefs>
      <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```